# Validating a Self Tracking Entity (EF) through WCF

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, self-tracking-entities, contract, operation

I'm having trouble defining what my `OperationContract` should be when adding / updating an entity. I want to send an entity (or list of entities) to the `ObjectContext` via the WCF Service (which will instantiate a Business Manager for me to do the actual validation).

If the  entity passes all of the validation rules (which could very well require querying the database to determine pass/fail for more complex business rules), it'll be saved to the database, and I'll need to be able to pass back its ID (Identity Column primary key) and the value of the concurrency token (timestamp column), but if it fails, obviously we want to have a message or messages saying what was wrong. In the case of an update, all we would need would be the new value of a concurrency token, but again we'd want the validation message(s).

To make it trickier, an entity could have multiple child/grandchild entities as well. For instance, a Trip will have Stops, which could potentially have Orders.

I'm just wondering how people handle this in the real world. The simplest examples just show the WCF service's operations like:

```
[OperationContract]
bool AddEntity(Entity e);

[OperationContract]
bool UpdateEntity(Entity e);
```

Does anyone have any great ideas for handling this? I guess I'm really just looking for practical advice here.

Should we be trying to save a collection of objects in one service call?

Should we be conveying the validation messages through a fault contract?

Any advice/input would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Should we be trying to save a
>   collection of objects in one service
>   call?

If you mean saving whole object graph in one call then the answer is definitely yes. If you mean saving multiple independent object graphs (collection) in one call then the answer is probably yes. It is good idea to reduce number of roundtrips between client and service to minimum but in the same time doing this can introduce complications. You must decide if the whole collection must be saved as atomic operation or if you are happy with saving only part of the collection and returning errors for the rest. This will influence the rest of your architecture.

> Should we be conveying the validation
>   messages through a fault contract?

Yes but only if you will use save operation as atomic because fault contract is exception and exception should break your current operation and return only validation errors. It should be enough to have single fault contract which will transfer all validation errors. Don't fire the exception for each single validation error because it can make your application pretty annoying and useless.

If you want to save only part of the collection which passes validations and return errors for the rest you should not use fault contracts. Instead of fault contracts you should have some container data contract used for response which will carry both ids and timestamps for saved data and ids and errors for unsaved data.

One little note to STEs: Passing back just Ids and timestamps can be probably tricky. I'm not sure if you don't have to turn off tracking when you want to set them and after that turn the tracking on again.